# Extract text between parentheses from string

Tags: regex, vbscript

I would like to split a string in VBScript using Regular Expressions.

The main goal is to return the content inside parentheses, for example:

```
strtoSplit = "Hello everyone! (27082015) What is your name? (123456789)"
```

Result: 27082015 123456789

I'm using this line of code but its not working:

```
strThatIWant = Split(strToSplit, "[\xA0]*\(([^)]+) \ )"
```

Can you help me with other solution or can you tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) cuts a string into an array of parts separated by a string (not a regexp). You are looking for the parts of an input string that are (made of) a sequence of digits. So you need a Regexp that specifies a sequence of digits: \d+.

```
>> strtoSplit = "Hello everyone! (27082015) What is your name? (123456789)"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> For Each m In r.Execute(strtoSplit)
>>     WScript.Echo m.Value
>> Next
>>
27082015
123456789
```

**On seconded thought:**

I should have understood from the start that you are interested in the parts 'between the parentheses'. So the pattern needs to change and we have to access a group:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\(([^)]+)\)"
>> For Each m In r.Execute(strtoSplit)
>>     WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
>> Next
>>
27082015
123456789
```

Comment: A non-greedy match might be a little more readable: `\((.+?)\)`.